# Is there an issue with having multiple eventListeners in one Javascript file?

Tags: javascript

So i have a JS file linked to my project.  Inside that file i have three buttons with eventListeners listening for a "click" on each.  The issue is that whichever button is placed first in the Javascript throws a "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" at that position.  I have checked everything spelling, assignment everyting but i still get the error.

When i split them up and place them in different JavaScript files there is no issue.  What am i missing?  am i making a noob mistake?  Here's my code for reference:

```
const btnsignUp = document.querySelector('.btnSU')
const btnCancel = document.querySelector('.btnCancel')

const auth = firebase.auth()

btnsignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {

    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username.value, 
    pwd1.value)
    promise.catch(e => alert(e.message))

    alert("Signed Up")

}

const btnLogin = document.querySelector('.btnLogin')
const btnLogCncl = document.querySelector('.btnLogCncl')


const auth = firebase.auth()

btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {

    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginusrname.value, 
    loginpwd.value)
    promise.catch(e=>alert(e.message))

    alert("Signed In " + loginusrname.value)
    window.open("/report.html")
})
```

Comment: it looks like the classic mistake of putting the HTML code in the Header of your page ...

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Also, not checking if the element exists is a rookie mistake.

Comment: To expand on what @MichaelMano said your error message: "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" was telling you where the problem is. your element was null, or in otherwords didn't exist and therefore didn't have the `addEventListener` property to begin with

Comment: Please properly indent your code. This is an eyesore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the element hasn't loaded yet (this is just a possible answer since you haven't provided enough code to verify this).

You can solve this by putting your script tag at the bottom of your page, right before your `</html>`, or you could wrap the whole code in a function, and call it buy doing `<body onload="myFunction()">` ([look at this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)), or you can use Jquery and put it in the callback function: `$(document).ready(() => {...});`.